# PAW: Remembering trusted self-signed certifiicates

Tags: paw-app

I am developing an API using a local server with a self signed SSL certificate.

Every time I make a request with PAW I get a dialog warning me that the certificate is self signed, and asking me if I would like to proceed.

This gets tiresome after the first few hundred requests.

Is there a way to tell PAW that I trust this certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- When the alert "Paw can't verify the identify of the remote server..." is shown
- Click "Show Certificate"
- Check the box "Always trust ... when connecting to ..."
- Hit "Continue"
- You probably will have to enter your system password to allow the Keychain to mark this certificate as trusted

Then on next calls, it won't prompt you again. See the short screencast here: http://cl.ly/3r102z170X3F

An alternative (but unsafe) way is to uncheck "Validate SSL Certificates" in the Preferences (Paw menu > Preferences), under the "HTTP" tab.

Hope this helps!